# Instagram official app

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps, store, instagram

Is there a definite way to get the OFFICIAL Instagram app not the unofficial app on Windows 10 Mobile? Because in the Microsoft store all I find is the unofficial one and I can get it on my Windows 10 computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Instagram app is available here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/instagram/9nblggh5l9xt?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

If you don't see it on your phone, make sure it meets the minimum requirements.